# How to convert SDK PageMod() to Webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I use `pageMod()` in my **Firefox** **SDK** app, and i want to convert to **Webextension**.

I declare on top on my background js file:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
```

I have undesrtood in **Webextension** is declared in `manifest.json`

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mytestsite.com/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ]
```

But i call `pageMod()` inside my `background` script and i have a lot of attachment and other. I dont know how i can convert this.

**For example what i want convert:**

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mytestsite.com",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-2.0.3.min.js"), self.data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"), self.data.url("site_modal_min.js"), self.data.url("timerreview.js")],
  onAttach: function onAttach(worker) {
```

How use my `PageMod()` call with **Webxtension**

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in manifest.json, you cannot have background.js inside of a content_scripts tag. You would instead do it like this (assuming your match selector for the domain is correct):

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.mytestsite.com/*"],
    "js": ["timerreview.js", "jquery.js"]
  }
]
```

If you want to communicate (variables, etc) use messaging between the background script and the content script. This is especially useful since most of the WebExtensions API is only available for background scripts.

In the content script, add:

```
// Listen for messages from the background script
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessage);

function onMessage(message) {
    switch(message.action)
        case "testAction":
            testAction(message.data);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function sendMessage(action, data){
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({"action": action, "data": data});
}
```

In the background script, add:

```
// listen for messages from the content or options script
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case "actionFromContent":
            doSomething(); // message.data is not needed
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});

// See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/sendMessage
function sendMessage(action, data){
    function logTabs(tabs) {
        for (tab of tabs) {
            browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"action": action, "data": data}).catch(function(){
                onError("failed to execute " + action + "with data " + data);
            });
        }
    }

    browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}).then(logTabs, onError);
}

function onError(error){
    console.error(error);
}
```

Now you can use:

```
sendMessage("actionFromContent") from within the content script to send a message to the background script
sendMessage("testAction", "someData") from within the background script to the active content script (the active tab)
```